# sed with doublequotes and $

Tags: ssh, sed, double-quotes

I have a bash script that I use to setup a simple php script on my server. I am stuck with how to correctly change a variable with `sed` with the script. Here is what I have tried:

```
echo "Enter Portal Password:"
read PORTPASS;
sed -i 's/$ppass =".*"/$ppass ="$PORTPASS"/' includes/config.php
```

The above changes the variable in the config file but it only changes it to `$PORTPASS` it does not change it to what I input in the script.

I also tried this and it does change the `$PORTPASS` correctly, but it remove the `" "` around the variable in the file.

```
sed -i 's/$ppass ='".*"'/$ppass ='"$PORTPASS"';/' includes/config.php
```

Here is what I'm trying to change in the conf.php file: `$ppass ="password";`

Comment: why do you have ssh in the title? Are you trying to remotely change config.php? If so, please edit your question to include this information, else edit your title. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
sed -i "s/\$ppass =\".*\"/\$ppass =\"$PORTPASS\"/" includes/config.php
```

You have to use double quotes (`"`) around the command so that the shell will evaluate `$PORTPASS` before passing it to sed, so then you have to "escape" all of the double quotes within the command.

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) The only weird thing is it also replaced the varibles below as well, ie, after changing the password heres what I get: $ppass ="cheese";
$css ="cheese";
$filedir ="cheese";

Comment: @user1792287: Sorry, my mistake, I forgot to escape the `$` in front of "ppass"; the shell evaluated it as nothing (it has no such variable), so sed just changed ` =".*"` to ` ="cheese"` everywhere. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, I used your updated code and it does not appear to change the password.

Comment: @user1792287: I made a bad assumption. Third time's the charm.